# How to use the ISEMPTY function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning SQL and using Myworkbench to do so. The error is pointing to the isempty function. Where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT a.ParcelID, a.PropertyAddress, b.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, 
isempty(a.propertyAddress,b.propertyAddress) 
FROM portfolioproject.nashvillehousing a
join nashvillehousing b
on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
where a.PropertyAddress = '';
```

Comment: use coalesce(a.propertyAddress,b.propertyAddress)

Comment: Does this help https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_isempty/ does not seem relevant to how you are trying to use it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

```
SELECT a.ParcelID, a.PropertyAddress, b.ParcelID, b.PropertyAddress, 
COALESCE(a.propertyAddress,b.propertyAddress) 
FROM portfolioproject.nashvillehousing a
join nashvillehousing b
on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
where a.PropertyAddress = '';
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Coalesce seems to have worked. I thought I'd be able to do the rest but the next line isn't working either @nk 

`update a set PropertyAddress = coalesce(b.PropertyAddress, a.PropertyAddress) from portfolioproject.nashvillehousing a join nashvillehousing b on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID where a.PropertyAddress = '');`

Comment: Your syntax is wrong ` update portfolioproject.nashvillehousing a join nashvillehousing b on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID 
 set a.PropertyAddress = coalesce(b.PropertyAddress, a.PropertyAddress) 
where a.PropertyAddress = '';

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I do have a lot to learn. Respect